# focus does not enter targeted user control properly

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls, focus

I've got a user control, consisting of a text box and two buttons. 
the control is placed on a dialog box and when i tab over the dialog
controls, I experience proper behavior - first the text box is focused,
then one button, then the other. 
However, when I set the user control as a target of a keyboard shortcut 
set with "_" for a label (say press alt+r for "_Row count") the user control
does not receive any focus.  Tried implementing "gotkeyboardfocus" and setting
the focus to the textbox control there but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A UserControl isn't focusable by default so you have to turn it on in order to get this to work.

```
<my:UserControl1 x:Name="userControl11" Focusable="True" .../>
<Label Target="userControl11">_Row count</Label>
```

And then you can focus the desired TextBox inside of the UserControl when it recieves Focus

```
private void UserControl_GotFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    textBox.Focus();
}
```

Comment: The GotFocus/Focus technique seems pretty ugly, but I'm not sure of a better way to do it.

Comment: Indeed it does.. Setting userControl.textBox doesn't work so I can't think of a better way either

Comment: this works, thank you. I would just make sure in the event handler that the object is not yet focused - otherwise you cannot tab out of it.

Answer (score 0):

Hi I recently encountered focus problem. What I did is create a method called SetFocus() from inside my user control. Then inside that usercontrol I set the focus directly to my textbox control after calling .SetFocus() from consumer.

```
public void SetFocus()
{
this.txtCommand.Focus();
}
```